# Discord bot with Webpanel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I want to make some bigger discord bot. I know how to make a bot and everything but i'm wondering about making an webpanel. Can someone explain how to make one of those and integrate with bot?

Comment: please explain what you mean by webPanel. do you a webpage you go to (hosted along side your bot)? if so i would say use express for node and then host a webpage with it.

Comment: By webpanel i mean an control panel in site for a discord bot (like mee6 etc)

Comment: yea the backend (which is just a normal website) that allows you to do advanced management on your bot. you will need to make a normal or frameworked website for this hence the express.js for node

Comment: Do you have links for some tutorials/documentations?

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use express.js in your node discord bot check out [Express](https://expressjs.com/) for more in depth examples. and if you want to look into socket connections [Socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat) has great tutorials on building socket connected apps. I prefer building the front end of my node apps in [Angular](https://angular.io/)

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = require('express')();

// these are for parsing POST requests
// alternatively you can use socket.io for real time communication 
// but POST'sshould suffice 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// GET requests like this first argument is url
// example; '*': all; '/home', '/something'
app.get('*', (req,res)=>{ /* process get request */ });

// POST requests
app.post('*', post.process);

// listen on your port eg: 80
http.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('Listening on port: '+port);
})
```